# Live Note detection C++

Tags: linux, c++, audio, debian

Am trying to create a project using rock pi that will be able to a handle microphone input and then find specific note that person is singing during a live demonstration. Searched online to see what c++ library already applies fft analysis however haven’t found effect references in c++ that may help me implement my project. Wondering if anybody can link a reference I can use in c++ or guide to me another path?

Tried using aubio-tools, and used Alsa-tools to understand what I may expect if my note detection software ever worked